# Android Kotlin Passed data with Safe Args Navigation returned null

Tags: android, kotlin

So here I have two fragments that are supposed to pass a data from one to another with Safe Args Navigation.

The first fragment (`OrderListFragment.kt`) supposed to pass an argument to the second fragment (`OrderDetailFragment.kt`).

This is the code snippet from the `navigation.xml`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

...
...


<action android:id="@+id/toOrderDetailFragment"
    app:destination="@+id/orderDetailFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="orderId"
        app:argType="string" /> <- This is what I want to Pass
</action>

...
...

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderListFragment"
        android:name="something.mainFragments.OrderListFragment"
        android:label="OrderListFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_orderListFragment_to_orderDetailFragment"
            app:destination="@id/orderDetailFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" >
        </action>
    </fragment>

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderDetailFragment"
        android:name="something.mainFragments.OrderDetailFragment"
        android:label="OrderDetailFragment" >
        <argument
            android:name="orderId"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

  ...
...
...
```

And this is the snippet from `OrderListFragment.kt` (It is a recyclerview that look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiPm2.png)).

**OrderListFragment.kt**

```
override fun onItemClicked(order: OutstandingOrderListPOJODataClassDataItem) {
    //Navigate to Detail Fragment

    Log.i("Order", "Clicked Item from order List: ${order.orderId}") <- I use this for debugging

    findNavController().navigate(
        NavigationDirections.toOrderDetailFragment(
            order.orderId
        )
    )
}
```

I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the recyclerview adapter since the `Log.i()` returns the value from the item i clicked. You can see it here[image: here].

As you can see from above, the first line is from `OrderListFragment.kt` when I clicked the Item. And the second line is from the `OrderDetailFragment.kt` where the value is supposed to passed on to.

Here's the snippet from `OrderDetailFragment.kt`:

**OrderDetailFragment.kt**

```
class OrderDetailFragment : Fragment(), OrderedItemListOnItemClickListener {

private val args = arguments?.let { OrderDetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it) }
private val selectedOrderId = args?.orderId

lateinit var adapter: OrderedItemListAdapter
private lateinit var binding: FragmentOrderDetailBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // Change action bar title
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Order Details"


    // View Binding for this Fragment
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_order_detail, container, false
    )

    fetchOrderDetail()
    fetchOrderedItemListData()
    Log.i("Order", "CLicked order ID: $selectedOrderId") <- The second line of the LOg message in the screen shot is from this line.

    //Inflate layout to this activity fragment
    return binding.root
}

    ....
    ....
    ....
```

Just for information, I fetch all the data in `OrderListFragment.kt` from an API endpoint with retrofit and parse them in a Data Class. :

```
data class OutstandingOrderListPOJODataClass(

    @field:SerializedName("data")
    val data: List<OutstandingOrderListPOJODataClassDataItem?>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("error")
    val error: Error? = null
)

data class OutstandingOrderListPOJODataClassDataItem(

    @field:SerializedName("buyer_address")
    @Expose
    val buyerAddress: String,

    @field:SerializedName("total_price")
    @Expose
    val totalPrice: Int,

    @field:SerializedName("buyer_name")
    @Expose
    val buyerName: String,

    @field:SerializedName("status_confirmed_yn")
    @Expose
    val statusConfirmedYn: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_date")
    @Expose
    val orderDate: String,

    @field:SerializedName("outlet_id")
    @Expose
    val outletId: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("nip")
    @Expose
    val nip: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("jumlah_product")
    @Expose
    val jumlahProduct: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("last_update")
    @Expose
    val lastUpdate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("phone_number")
    @Expose
    val phoneNumber: String,

    @field:SerializedName("order_running_id")
    @Expose
    val orderRunningId: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("status_tagged_yn")
    @Expose
    val statusTaggedYn: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("order_id")
    @Expose
    val orderId: String
)
```

Am I missing something ? If there's any detail that I missed to point out, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hello, I can not see something in your code; just to ensure you added `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"` to your gradle

Comment: another thing that you may check to transfer `Log.i("Order", "CLicked order ID: $selectedOrderId")` to `onViewCreated()`

Comment: @Zain  Thanks for your help. I just figured it out myself. So all I need to do is just move the declaration of  `val args` and `val selectedOrderId` into the `OnCreated()`. I'll Just write down the answer.

Comment: Good for you buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just figure it out myself. All I need to do is just move the declaration of `val args` and `val selectedOrderId` into the `OnCreated()`.

```
class OrderDetailFragment : Fragment(), OrderedItemListOnItemClickListener {


    lateinit var adapter: OrderedItemListAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentOrderDetailBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val args = arguments?.let { OrderDetailFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it) }
        val selectedOrderId = args?.orderId

        ....
        ....
        ....
```